# How to list the files using sort command but not ls -lrt command

Tags: linux, bash

I am writing a shell script to check some parameters like errors or exception inside the log files which are getting generated in last 2 hours inside the directory /var/log. So this is command I am using:

```
find /var/log -mmin -120|xargs egrep -i "error|exception"
```

It is displaying the list of file names and its corresponding parameters(errors and exceptions) but the list of files are not as per the time sequence. I mean the output is something like this(the sequence):

```
/var/log/123.log:RPM returned error
/var/log/361.log:There is error in line 1
/var/log/4w1.log:Error in configuration line
```

But the sequence how these 3 log files have been generated is different.

```
/var/log>ls -lrt
Dec24 1:19 361.log
Dec24 2:01 4w1.log
Dec24 2:15 123.log
```

So I want the output in the same sequence,I mean like this:

```
/var/log/361.log:There is error in line 1
/var/log/4w1.log:Error in configuration line
/var/log/123.log:RPM returned error
```

I tried this:

```
find /var/log -mmin -120|ls -ltr|xargs egrep -i "error|exception"
```

but it is not working.
Any help on this is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prepend the modified time using the `-printf` argument to `find`, then `sort`, and then remove the modified time with `sed`:

```
find /var/log -mmin -120 -printf '%T@:%p\n' | sort -V | sed -r 's/^[^:]+://' | xargs egrep -i "error|exception"
```

- `find ... -printf '%T@:%p\n'` prints out each found file (`%p`) prepended by the seconds since the UNIX epoch (`%T@`; e.g., `1419433217.1835886710`) and a colon separator (`:`), each on a new line (`\n`).
- `sort -V` sorts the files naturally by modification time because it is at the beginning of each line (e.g., `1419433217.1835886710:path/to/the/file`).
- `sed -r 's/^[^:]+://'` takes each line in the format `123456789.1234:path/to/the/file` and strips out the modification time leaving just the file path `path/to/the/file`

Answer (score 1):

If your filenames don't have any special characters (like newline characters, etc), all you need is another call to `xargs`:

```
find . -type f -mmin -120 | xargs ls -tr | xargs egrep -i "error|exception"
```

Or if your filenames contain said special chars:

```
find . -type f -mmin -120 -print0 | xargs -0 ls -tr | xargs egrep -i "error|exception"
```